# In cloudera 5.13.0 services are not starting

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have mistakenly deleted `/var/log/*` folder, due to that the services were not starting in Cloudera which were installed in that specific node. And the log files are not getting generated. And no clear error message available in cloudera manager. Can someone please suggest me how to proceed further.

Please find the below image for your understanding.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: namenode should be  formatted  before  your started it

Comment: But i will loose the data if i format it. The cluster is already having some data, which i don't want to loose.

Comment: how  about  use shell comand  ' daemon.sh start namenode‘ ,  please give more  message

Comment: The image link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create empty folders like

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/hadoop-hdfs
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/cloudera-scm-server
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/hadoop-mapreduce
```

etc.. based on your services selected in Cloudera Manager. Because Cloudera doesn't create the log directories(It just creates the file)

You can test it by doing a global search in Cloudera Manager with `/var/log` and you will find a lot of log directory names. Just created it. It should work

Comment: The file permissions might need fixed too

Comment: Thanks i have created them. And in few places it is also expecting the log files. Also, i have updated user:group using chown command. post that it started.